# Gradle : dependency license for Java/Spring library

Tags: java, spring, gradle, build.gradle, gradle-eclipse

I have a Java/SpringREST project setup using Gradle. Is there a way in Gradle to generate a report of all dependencies (jar library) and license info of each dependency.

Comment: Please add the code you have written so far.

Comment: do you mean the build.gradle file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the content very helpful and it solved my problem : [Robert Fischer-Gradle License Report](https://github.com/RobertFischer/Gradle-License-Report)